# Grails: How to create a clear button?

Tags: button, grails, groovy, filter

Hello I have created a filter for my list. In a template named `_search.gsp`
And I need a clear button that clears out all the fields in the filter.
I have one textField named `proyectoRutaN`
And four datePickers named `fechaCambioD` , `fechaCambioH` , `lastUpdatedD`, and `lastUpdatedH`

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

-Fernando

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can just use the html tag:

```
<input type='reset' value='Reset' />
```

within your form.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use g:field as per other input types:

```
<g:field type="reset" name="myReset" value="Reset" />
```